# Basic SQL - Using temp table; The multi-part identifier "mytable.Number" could not be bound

Tags: sql, temp-tables

I'd like to declare a temp table and then reference a single number I pass into it at creation.

```
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
    #my_table
SELECT 
    Number
INTO 
    #my_table
FROM
    MyDB1.dbo.MyTable
WHERE 
    NumberTwo = '(user provided input)'

UPDATE 
    WorkingTable
SET
    SerialNo = Bar.SerialNo, 
    Make = Bar.Make, 
    Model = Bar.Model,
    UnitNo = Bar.UnitNo, 
    Time = Bar.Time
FROM 
    MyDB1.dbo.AnotherTable as Bar
    My_Table as Foo
WHERE 
       Bar.SerialNo = Foo.Number
AND 
       ThirdTable.ThisNumber = '(user provided input)'

COMMIT
```

but it keeps failing for "the multi-part identifier "my_table" could not be bound" and I've been unable to sus out why.
I know it's because in the Update the temp table "my_table" isn't found / referenced correctly but that's about all I know - I don't write SQL much myself, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` is used when you multiple tables in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing the `#` symbol.

Try it like this:

```sql
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
    #my_table
SELECT 
    Number
INTO 
    #my_table
FROM
    MyDB1.dbo.MyTable
WHERE 
    NumberTwo = '(user provided input)'

UPDATE 
    WorkingTable
SET
    SerialNo = Bar.SerialNo, 
    Make = Bar.Make, 
    Model = Bar.Model,
    UnitNo = Bar.UnitNo, 
    Time = Bar.Time
FROM 
    MyDB1.dbo.AnotherTable as Bar
    INNER JOIN #my_table as Foo
       ON Bar.SerialNo = Foo.Number
WHERE ThirdTable.ThisNumber = '(user provided input)'

COMMIT
```

Comment: Not sure what `ThirdTable` is. It is likely that the query won't work until you join that table to the rest.